# Design forms in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Till current moment I knew only one recipy to create form VC++ designer:
1. Add dialog resource and design what you want in designer.
2. Create MFC form by using designed dialog resources

But now I got project sample that has form and has no *.rs files with form information. Instead of that it has header file that has form icon. Header file contains many code that creates controls and sets style. It is also possible select from menu "View Designer". That makes me think that there is another way of creating form. Besides that looks that codes does't uses MFC.

How to create simple form application with designer that would generate header file (not resource) and not use MFC?

Unfortunately I can't  "View Designer" because during this procedure error is generated:

```
C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 1520, Column: 42 --- Unknown type 'AxKgLib.AxKg'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.
```

Correct me if I'm wrong. Looks like I need registered ActiveX for this project. I have registered ocx that was included in source, but this didn't helped.

How to solve this problem? How to get list of all ocx that system has to make sure there is no required `AxKgLib.AxKg`? How to make designer to show me form without required control?

[image: Header]

Comment: That's what you would see if you added a .Net Windows Form, perhaps that form hosts an ActiveX component (AxKgLib.AxKg) thats does not exist and so breaks the designer, look in the file and see whats up.

Comment: But program compiles and run fine. Without ActiveX it wouldn't run?